# How can I change the format of the Qubit IDs of the Q# DumpMachine?

Tags: jupyter, q#

In Q#, the DumpMachine function gives an overview of the state of the quantum system. Its output (in a Q# Jupyter Notebook) looks like this:

[image: output of DumpMachine with basis states in little endian state]

Is there a way for me to change the way the basis states are represented? For example, in big endian, or even better, as a sequence of bits? (So: `|00>, |01>, |10>, |11>` instead of what I have above.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`%config` magic command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/iqsharp-magic/config) to change this setting.

For example, to configure `DumpMachine` to represent basis states as bit strings, you can use:

```
%config dump.basisStateLabelingConvention="Bitstring"
```

Supported options are `"LittleEndian"`, `"BigEndian"`, and `"Bitstring"`.